# EF Core 7.0 Json column type and entity configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to arrange new feature which is Json column types in EF Core 7.0 but i am not sure how to make entity configuration (https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=fluent-api%2Cpoco)

For example, I have a class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create table which looks like this:
Columns: Id (Guid), Deleted (bool), Data (json string)

Data in json column should look like:

```
{
    "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Deleted": false,
    "Name": "Example name",
    "Date": "2022-12-20T22:07:17Z"
}
```

How can i configure entity to get expected result?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow bartosz! i'm not quite sure what do you mean with json "column." did you meant in json form? afaik, if you [serialize your `Entity` to json using `System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) it will roughly looked like your example.

Comment: The answer seems to be in the link you provided. What have you tried?

Comment: [JSON Columns](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/)

Comment: JSON columns are implemented as "owned types" so you'd need a class to represent the table row, and a class to represent the json.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your models like this,

*DataEntity.cs*

```
public class DataEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

*OwnerEntity.cs*

```
public class OwnerEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public DataEntity Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now the key part is in your model configs,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OwnerEntity>().OwnsOne(
        owner => owner.Data, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
        {
            ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
        });
}
```

After you run the `Add-Migration` command, you should see the migration script like this,

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "OwnerEntities",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        Deleted = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
        Data = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_OwnerEntities", x => x.Id);
    });
```

Note that the Data column is `string` type.

A more detailed example can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/).